# Chrome dosen't show borders from CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a problem. I'm using Google Chrome, and not it will not show border om td, div or anything at all.

Like this code:

```
div#over-blue {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45;
    background-color: #54bdc9;
    border-bottom: 4 solid #38a5b2;
}
```

It will not show the border-bottom.

Any idea why? It had work, until yesterday, it just stop showing them.

Please help. I have tried to reinstall Chrome, tried on a PC and a MAC. It only works on my iPad...

Comment: Your lengths are missing units. If your CSS had worked until yesterday, then it was yesterday that a doctype declaration was introduced into your markup (when it should have been there to begin with, unless you're working on a legacy application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, you need to specify the px for the border. So it will be something like this:

```
div#over-blue {
width: 100%;
height: 45;
background-color: #54bdc9;
border-bottom: 4px solid #38a5b2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want "4px" not "4":

```css
div#over-blue {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45;
    background-color: #54bdc9;
 /* border-bottom: 4   solid #38a5b2; */  /* doesn't work */
    border-bottom: 4px solid #38a5b2;  /* works */
}
```

```html
<div> hi there
</div>

<div id="over-blue">
      I ought to have a border-bottom
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh... Thanks so much!!! It used to work with just 4, but ok they want 4px now... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add border unit and try "4px" instead of "4".